# How do i save data when user is logged in the app in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have implemented a login and register system when users can register and log with their username and password. Now, i am not sure how to even begin with this problem.

I want to save data, whatever he or she is doing in the app, to be there just for that user and not collide with the data with other users if that makes some sense at all.

So, my app have one master database with table (USER_INFO) that have 3 Columns, ID, NAME and PASSWORD.

My question is, how to implement saving method to SQLite for particular user? 
Should i create another table under my master db? and How?
If i have second table should i connected with USER_INFO table?

Tried to read from google android, but don't really answer me this question there.

Comment: What you want to save? which data?

Comment: User data. Like, making notes,user search, etc, any kind of data that the user will create

Comment: you want to save it like when the next time you visit or in the database?

Comment: Here is sample app.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same table, like this:

1) Your entity object

```
public class UserInfo {
    int id; // will be auto-increamted
    String name;
    String password;

    public UserInfo(int id, String name, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }
// getter/setters ...
}
```

2) Your Sqlite utility object, like (note you can add more tables, as you wish):

```
public class SQLiteDBAdapter {

    protected static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb";
    protected static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    protected Context context;
    protected static DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;

    public static final String TABLE_USER_INFO = "tbl_userinfo";
    // columns
    public static final String USER_ID = "_id";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "password";
    // create table string
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER_INFO =
            "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + TABLE_USER_INFO + " ( " +
                    USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    public SQLiteDBAdapter(Context context) {
      context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDb() {
      if (mDbHelper == null) {
          mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
      }
      return mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    protected static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
      // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
          super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }
      // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
          db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER_INFO);
      }
      // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
          Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " +
                  newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
          db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS routes");
          onCreate(db);
      }
    }
}
```

3) Extend an Sqlite object to manipulate the table (CRUD operations):

```
public class UserInfoDbAdapter extends SQLiteDBAdapter {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    // these are column corresponding indices
    public static final int INDEX_ID = 0;  // an auto-increment
    public static final int INDEX_NAME = 1;
    public static final int INDEX_PASSWORD = 2;

    public UserInfoDbAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void add(String name, String password) {
        db = openDb();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(NAME, name);
        values.put(PASSWORD, password);
        db.insert(TABLE_USER_INFO, null, values);
    }

    public void update(String name, String password) {
        db = openDb();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(NAME, name);
        values.put(PASSWORD, password);
        db.update(TABLE_USER_INFO, values, null);
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        db = openDb();
        db.delete(TABLE_USER_INFO, null, null);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        db = openDb();
        boolean empty = true;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE_USER_INFO, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            empty = (cursor.getInt (0) == 0);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return empty;
    }

    public UserInfo fetchRecord() { // only one record to fetch
        db = openDb();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER_INFO, new String[]{USER_ID, NAME, PASSWORD},
                null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null &&
            cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return new UserInfo(
                    cursor.getInt(INDEX_ID),
                    cursor.getString(INDEX_NAME),
                    cursor.getInt(INDEX_PASSWORD));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

4) Finally, add/update/delete/fetch user record as desired ...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private UserInfoDbAdapter userDB; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ... 
        // initialize user db
        userDB = new UserInfoDbAdapter(this);

        // add user if table is empty
        if (userDB.isEmpty() {
            // add user
            userDB.add(nameTextView.getText().toString(), passwordTextView.getText().toString());
// note it's always more secure to store encrypted password, rather than plain text.
        } else {
            // update
            userDB.update(nameTextView.getText().toString(), passwordTextView.getText().toString());
        }

    }
    ...
    // fetch record
    public UserInfo fetchRecord() {
        return userDB.fetchRecord();
    }
}
```

Comment: Really appreciated.